# Install glassfish on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, server

I try install glassfish on eclipse, but i got this error 
[Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq0y0.jpg)

i try  named  server root directory like also glassfish, but nothing chenged

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you should do is download the server .zip file from the glassfish website:

https://glassfish.java.net/download.html

Second, extract your .zip anywhere you want your server to be. If you download the latest version your directory should be "glassfish4".

Third, go into eclipse and then open the same dialogue. In server root, navigate to the glassfish directory that is inside the directory you just unzipped - "glassfish4". That directory is your server root path.

Then just select the jdk and click next. Have fun!